# The checked values clear when the page is refreshed. in h:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: selectmanycheckbox

I have a problem on using h:selectManyCheckbox. The checked values clear when the page is refreshed.
I have used JSF 1.2

> `<h:selectManyCheckbox value="${dmsParticipantsForm.filterCompany}"
>        style="text-align: left" class="companySelector"
>        layout="pageDirection" >
>        <f:selectItems value="${dmsActionForm.companies}" />
>    </h:selectManyCheckbox>`

Comment: Is it only one way to create JS function which will control state of selected values after reloading?

Answer (score 1):

Do you store selected values somewhere (for example in session)?
If so, you load selected values..

```
...

private List<Item> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>(); // getter-setter

@PostConstruct
public void prepare() {
    getSelectedItems().addAll(getSessionBeanOrOtherResource().getSelectedOrStoredValues());
}
```